# sumover vs sum with group by in AWS quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

### I am really confused what is the difference between using the sum aggregate function using the group by function in quicksight vs using the sumover function.
Example : calculating sum(avg(sales),[manager_name,department])

### sumOver(avg(sales),[manager_name,department])

I read their official documentation but I am really confused.